# store several images in the file system and all the references in the database

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I use `ImageField` fields in my form and model to upload images, but I need to be multiple images and that just store one image and one reference in de database, this is my code:

```
#models.py
class mymodel(models.Model):
    imgs = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/')

#forms.py
class myform(forms.Form):
    imgs = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'id': 'file', 'accept': 'image/*', 'multiple': True}))

#views.py
def myview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = myform(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                modelo = mymodel()
                modelo.imgs = form.cleaned_data.get('imgs')
                modelo.save()
```

When I do that only store one image even if I select 5 and in the database just store the path of the image that is stored

**How can I store the 5 imagen on disk and in the database in one register store the references of the 5 images using something like ',' to separete**

sorry for my bad english, If you need more information please ask me

Answer (score 0):

`mymodel.imgs` is an ImageField which only supports a single field. You might try using an [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) (if you're using postgres for your database) where the child field is an `ImageField`. Or you'll need to use a [form factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function).

Comment: I nedd just one field but with the `multiple` attribute accept several images